# Cut method for a card game in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, methods

I have a project for my computer science class that involves making a card game.  Here's a basic look at the Card.

```
public Card(int value, int suit) {
    if (value < 1 || value > 9) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Illegal card value attempted.  The " +
                "acceptible range is 1 to 9.  You tried " + value);
    }
    if (suit < 0 || suit > 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Illegal suit attempted.  The  " + 
                "acceptible range is 0 to 4.  You tried " + suit);
    }
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

/** 
 * "Getter" for value of Card.
 * @return value of card 
 */
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**==
 * "Getter" for suit of Card.

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}
```

The problem I am having is with the cut method.  With the cut method, the user basically selects a position in the ArrayList where they want the list to start from.  Anything in front of that position is moved to the back of the arraylist.  So an example would be if the ArrayList had values of [1 2 3 4 5] and the user selects the position 3 (which would be 4), the method returns a new ArrayList of [4 5 1 2 3].  Here's what I had in my code.

```
private ArrayList<Card> cards;

public void cut(int position) {
    Deck tophalf = new Deck();
    tophalf.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Deck bottomhalf = new Deck();
    bottomhalf.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Deck cutted = new Deck();
    cutted.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i=0; i<position; i++){
        bottomhalf.cards.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    for (int i=position; i<this.getNumCards(); i++){
        tophalf.cards.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<this.getNumCards()-(position+1); i++){
        cutted.cards.add(tophalf.getCardAt(i));
    }
    int pos=0;
    for (int i=this.getNumCards()-(position+1); i<this.getNumCards(); i++){

        cutted.cards.add(bottomhalf.getCardAt(pos));
        pos++;
    }
    this.cards=cutted.cards;
}
```

I get an error every time I run the code and it has to do with the pos variable.  I'm not sure what the specific error is.

Comment: could you please add the stacktrace you get?

Comment: Why not just do a `cutted.addAll(tophalf); cutted.addAll(bottomhalf);`? You could also use [`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

Comment: Thank you.   I wasn't sure if I was allowed by my professor to use the addAll function, but he said it was okay.